# fetching and displaying the backend json data as dropdown in an Ionic project

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, ionic4

Iam working in an ionic project, where my requirement is to get the backend json data through an api call and display the json content as dropdown in front end. below is the api call code,json format and code i tried.

Broker api call

```
http://example.com/broker/get-user-names
```

backend Json data:

```
{
    "USER_NAME": "John",
    "USER_COUNTRY": "USA"
},


{
    "USER_NAME": "Smith",
    "USER_COUNTRY": "Canada"
},


 {
    "USER_NAME": "Peter",
    "USER_COUNTRY": "Russia"
},
```

I wanted to create a dropdown where i want to get all the usernames in dropdwon to select, i have created a method in .ts files, below the method

```
 getUserNames() {
this.apiService.getUserNames(this.apiService.loggedInUser.value.id).then(
  res => {
     this.userNames= res;
     alert(JSON.stringify(this.userNames));

  },
  err => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(err))
  }
)
}
```

In .html file

```
  <ion-select placeholder="Select One">

          <ion-select-option selected="true" >{{userNames.USER_NAME}}-</ion-select-option>

 </ion-select>
```

But its displaying only the first user name i.e JOHN in my case as json data contains john as first username.

How can i do to display all the usernames as dropdowns from the backend json data.

please help me on this , i got struck in this from last 1 week.

thanks

Comment: Is this.userNames an array?

Answer (score 1):

Provided `this.userNames` is an array, use:

```
<ion-select-option *ngFor="let user of userNames">{{user.USER_NAME}}-</ion-select-option>
```

.ts

Create an array to hold the data you get from the API

```
userNames = [];
```

now in the subscription block:

```
getUserNames() {
   this.apiService.getUserNames(this.apiService.loggedInUser.value.id)
     .subscribe(res => {
        this.userNames= res;
        alert(JSON.stringify(this.userNames)); 
     },
     err => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(err))
     }
   )
}
```

Comment: hi @Nicholas, thanks for your response. but i haven't created any array there. please help how can i do here to get the output

Comment: What is `this.userNames` in your .ts file?

Comment: userNames is the model name which i created and written the json format there. i am newbie to ionic and angualar. i did this by searcing online. please help me

Comment: Define it as `userNames = []` as a field in your typescript file.

Comment: hi @Nicholas, No. I didnt understand how to proceed because iam retrieving data from the backend broker.  how can i store the backend json data in an array. the data might change and will get update in future. any help on this will be greatly appreciated. thank you